# How can I use the Tailwind CSS CLI (and postcss) to input and output an entire folder with same file names

Tags: wordpress, npm, tailwind-css, postcss, npm-package

I'm currently using WordPress and Tailwind CSS, specifically [Tailpress](https://tailpress.io/), and I'd like to take in all `css` files from `./resources/css/components` and output to `./css/components`, running postcss and whatever processing is necessary. The rest of the project is configured to output from `./resources/css` to `./css` and works fine. I tried adding `css/components`, `css/components/`, `css/components/*` and some other intuitive syntaxes, but to no avail. I've tried googling for quite a while and searching the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) and stackoverflow and can't find anything on outputting an entire directory of files.

I know bundlers like rollup or vite could take in files and output obscurified or semi-random file names and they have often config for keeping the file names the same. Am I looking in the wrong place thinking the tailwindcss CLI could do this? The rest of the project uses the tailwindcss CLI for the individual `app.css` and `editor-style.css` input and output, but we do have `esbuild` for JS only. Here are the scripts in the `package.json` which is the default Tailpress one with my added (not working) component CSS scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "production:css-app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/app.css -o ./css/app.css --postcss --minify",
    "production:css-components": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/components -o ./css/components --postcss --minify",
    "production:css-editor": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/editor-style.css -o ./css/editor-style.css --postcss --minify",
    "production:js": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/esbuild ./resources/js/app.js --bundle --outfile=./js/app.js --minify",
    "dev:css-app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/app.css -o ./css/app.css --postcss",
    "dev:css-components": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/components -o ./css/components --postcss",
    "dev:css-editor": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/editor-style.css -o ./css/editor-style.css --postcss",
    "dev:js": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/esbuild ./resources/js/app.js --bundle --outfile=./js/app.js",
    "watch:css-app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/app.css -o ./css/app.css --postcss --watch",
    "watch:css-components": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/components -o ./css/components --postcss --watch",
    "watch:css-editor": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/editor-style.css -o ./css/editor-style.css --postcss --watch",
    "watch:js": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/esbuild ./resources/js/app.js --bundle --outfile=./js/app.js --watch",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production concurrently \"npm run production:css-app\" \"npm run production:css-components\" \"npm run production:css-editor\" \"npm run production:js\"",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"npm run dev:css-app\" \"npm run dev:css-components\" \"npm run dev:css-editor\" \"npm run dev:js\"",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"npm run watch:css-app\" \"npm run watch:css-components\" \"npm run watch:css-editor\" \"npm run watch:js\"",
    "browser-sync": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development browser-sync start --proxy \"trulioo-twenty-two.test\" --host=\"trulioo-twenty-two.test\" --no-inject-changes --files=\"./\"",
    "watch-sync": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"npm run browser-sync\" \"npm run watch\""
  },
```

Comment: So every command here is from tailpress except the "components" ones which I added. It's already setup to handle individual files but I want to do the whole folder. Sounds like something a bundler would do, and this project uses esbuild, but it only uses esbuild for JS

Answer (score 0):

So the [Tailwindcss CLI docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/tailwind-cli) are pretty bad... But I found that I could accomplish this with `postcss-cli`

`npm install postcss-cli`

`"components": "postcss resources/css/components/ --dir css/components/",`

Of course, rename the script to anything you want and change the source and destination directories.